# Is it possible to use event handlers in Asp Net Web Api controllers?

Tags: asp.net, controller, event-handling, signalr, signalr-hub

I have a web api controller and I would like to use event handlers in it. To be more specific I have a `MessagesController` and when the action method `WriteMessage` is executed I would like to trigger an event to which a `SignalR Hub method` will be subscribed and this method will broadcast the message to all the necessary receivers. Take a look at the simplified code below:

This is the controller:

```
public class MessagesController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IMessageService _messageService;
    public EventHandler<MessageEventArgs> MessageSent;

    public MessagesController(IMessageService messageService)
    {
        _messageService = messageService;
    }

    public IHttpActionResult WriteMessage(Message message)
    {
        try
        {
            //here I'm using MessageService to write the message to the data base
            _messageService.WriteMessage(message);

            //after the message was saved successfully I would like to trigger the event that will fire a signalR hub's method
            OnMessageSent(message);
            return Content(HttpStatusCode.Created, message);
        }
        //some exception handling
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ...
        }
    }

    protected void OnMessageSent(Message message)
    {
        if (MessageSent!= null)
            MessageSent(this,new MessageEventArgs{Message = message});
    }
}
```

This is the SignalR hub (this is just a quick outline, I haven't tested it yet):

```
public class MessagesHub : Hub
{
    public static void Send(string message)
    {
        Clients.All.send(message);
    }

    public void OnMessageSent(object source, MessageEventArgs args)
    {
        Send(args.Message.Text);
    }
}
```

Now I would like to somehow subscribe to the controller's event handler. If it was a regular class I would do something like this:

`messagesController.MessageSent+=messagesHub.OnMessageSent`

Since this is a controller, and I have no control over its creation, I probably won't be able to do the above. Of course I could refrain from using events and just call `MessagesHub.Send` directly in the controller's method, but the event-driven approach will decouple `SiganlR` from the controller and overall seems to be a more elegant solution. Can you advise something?

Comment: Probably, it depends on what you are trying to achieve. In .net world you can use `event` keyword with an any kind of framework (including AspNet WebAPI) because the language itself supports it. So nothing can stop you form defining the event in this controller, subscribe to it in a constructor and raising it during `WriteMessage` call. Another story will be 'how to properly configure DI Container`.